# QT Linker errors with boost iostreams

Tags: c++, qt, boost, boost-iostreams

I am trying to compile a Qt 5.5 application using msvc2010. However whenever I try to build it I get several linker errors all relating to boost::iostreams.

```
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::reset(void)" (?reset@gzip_header@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::gzip_header(void)" (??0gzip_header@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE@XZ)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_footer::reset(void)" (?reset@gzip_footer@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_footer::gzip_footer(void)" (??0gzip_footer@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE@XZ)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::default_compression" (?default_compression@zlib@iostreams@boost@@3HB)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::deflated" (?deflated@zlib@iostreams@boost@@3HB)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::default_strategy" (?default_strategy@zlib@iostreams@boost@@3HB)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::~zlib_base(void)" (??1zlib_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0?$zlib_decompressor_impl@V?$allocator@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE@ABUzlib_params@23@@Z$0
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::zlib_base(void)" (??0zlib_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<class std::allocator<char> >::zlib_decompressor_impl<class std::allocator<char> >(struct boost::iostreams::zlib_params const &)" (??0?$zlib_decompressor_impl@V?$allocator@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE@ABUzlib_params@23@@Z)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::reset(bool,bool)" (?reset@zlib_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAEX_N0@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<class std::allocator<char> >::~zlib_decompressor_impl<class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$zlib_decompressor_impl@V?$allocator@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE@XZ)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::do_init(struct boost::iostreams::zlib_params const &,bool,void * (__cdecl*)(void *,unsigned int,unsigned int),void (__cdecl*)(void *,void *),void *)" (?do_init@zlib_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@AAEXABUzlib_params@34@_NP6APAXPAXII@ZP6AX22@Z2@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::init<class std::allocator<char> >(struct boost::iostreams::zlib_params const &,bool,struct boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_allocator<class std::allocator<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &)" (??$init@V?$allocator@D@std@@@zlib_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAEXABUzlib_params@23@_NAAU?$zlib_allocator@V?$allocator@D@std@@V12@@123@@Z)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_footer::process(char)" (?process@gzip_footer@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAEXD@Z) referenced in function __catch$??$read@V?$linked_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@@?$basic_gzip_decompressor@V?$allocator@D@std@@@iostreams@boost@@QAE_JAAV?$linked_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@detail@12@PAD_J@Z$0
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::process(char)" (?process@gzip_header@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAEXD@Z) referenced in function "public: __int64 __thiscall boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<class std::allocator<char> >::read<class boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > >(class boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char *,__int64)" (??$read@V?$linked_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@@?$basic_gzip_decompressor@V?$allocator@D@std@@@iostreams@boost@@QAE_JAAV?$linked_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@detail@12@PAD_J@Z)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::okay" (?okay@zlib@iostreams@boost@@3HB)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::stream_end" (?stream_end@zlib@iostreams@boost@@3HB)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::iostreams::zlib_error::check(int)" (?check@zlib_error@iostreams@boost@@SAXH@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<class std::allocator<char> >::filter(char const * &,char const *,char * &,char *,bool)" (?filter@?$zlib_decompressor_impl@V?$allocator@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE_NAAPBDPBDAAPADPAD_N@Z)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::after(char const * &,char * &,bool)" (?after@zlib_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAEXAAPBDAAPAD_N@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<class std::allocator<char> >::filter(char const * &,char const *,char * &,char *,bool)" (?filter@?$zlib_decompressor_impl@V?$allocator@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE_NAAPBDPBDAAPADPAD_N@Z)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: int __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::xinflate(int)" (?xinflate@zlib_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAEHH@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<class std::allocator<char> >::filter(char const * &,char const *,char * &,char *,bool)" (?filter@?$zlib_decompressor_impl@V?$allocator@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE_NAAPBDPBDAAPADPAD_N@Z)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::zlib::sync_flush" (?sync_flush@zlib@iostreams@boost@@3HB)
packagehandler.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::before(char const * &,char const *,char * &,char *)" (?before@zlib_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAEXAAPBDPBDAAPADPAD@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<class std::allocator<char> >::filter(char const * &,char const *,char * &,char *,bool)" (?filter@?$zlib_decompressor_impl@V?$allocator@D@std@@@detail@iostreams@boost@@QAE_NAAPBDPBDAAPADPAD_N@Z)
debug\EmbeddedBoardTestScriptUtility.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 18 unresolved externals
```

Comment: TL;DR: All C++ code that uses C++ APIs, when linked together must be compiled using the same major release of Visual Studio, at the very least.

Comment: @KubaOber Perhaps my question was unclear, I rebuilt boost for msvc2010. I'm not using the msvc2008 .dlls

Comment: @Birdfriender have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if libboost_iostreams .lib library is available in your Boost libraries directory and if if is correctly linked in linking directories and linked libraries in linker project settings.

If you have compiled boost and have doubts on boost compilation (it can be compiled with many options excluding some projects) you can use precompiled binaries available on sourceforge [1].

[1] https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.60.0/

Comment: It is available, I tried renaming the file and the program failed to compile at all, never made it to the linker.

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one version of Boost on your PC? For which architecture are you compiling (32 bit or 64 bit)? The version of Boost you are linking is the same architecture you are trying to compile?

Comment: I have two versions of boost installed (One compiled for msvc2008 and one for msvc2010) but I have confirmed that it is trying to link to the correct one. And yeah, both are 32 bit. I tested with boost::chrono and that links correctly, it seems to be specifically an issue with this library.

Comment: Could it be a problem with version of Boost? When I have these types of problems I try to avoid having more versions of the same library on my PC and I remove all except the right one.

Comment: It could be but it seems unlikely, I tried renaming the 2010 libraries and the program failed to compile at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build boost with zlib enabeled. During the configuration phase boost will try to locate zlib and if succesfull you should see something like this when running the b2 command.

[image: boost configure finding zlib]

On most *nix platforms you need to install the zlib dev package. On Windows you need find/build zlib binaries and set these 3 environment variables before compiling boost.

ZLIB_BINARY
ZLIB_INCLUDE
ZLIB_LIBPATH

See this boost documentation:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iostreams/doc/installation.html